# what does the line "dec = (2 * dec) + (b[i] - '0');" do in this code

Tags: c, for-loop, binary, char, c-strings

```
#include "main.h"

/**
 * binary_to_uint - converts binary to unsigned int
 * @b: pointing to the binary number to be converted
 * Return: the converted number or
 * 0 if b is NULL or b is not 0 or 1.
 */

unsigned int binary_to_uint(const char *b)
{
    int i;

    unsigned int dec = 0;

    if (!b)
        return (0);

    for (i = 0; b[i]; i++)
    {
        if (b[i] < '0' || b[i] > '1')
            return (0);

        dec = (2 * dec) + (b[i] - '0');
    }

    return (dec);
}
```

Comment: The `-'0'` part is converting a digit from it's character representation to an actual number (that is `'1'` becomes `1`). The rest is math.

Comment: I may be asking a stupid question but shouldn't it be `(dec << 1) | (b[i] - '0');` ? It's been years since I've used bitshifting operators

Comment: @SomerandomITboy: that works, too. And pretty well every serious compiler understands that, too, and will insert whichever one is faster.

Answer (score 4):

The line `dec = (2 * dec) + (b[i] - '0');` adds a bit to the `dec` accumulator.

Multiplying by 2 shifts the bits left and dividing an unsigned or positive value by two shifts them to the right:

- 1 -> 0001 ; x2 = 2 -> 0010
- 2 -> 0010 ; x2 = 4 -> 0100

And that's what's `(2 * dec)` doing. Essentially another way of writing `dec << 1`.

`b[i]` is a character, which will be promoted to `int` for the subtraction, its value depends on the encoding used in the system, almost always ASCII nowadays, so the value of `b[i]` is the ASCII code for the binary digit.

Since beforehand there are checks that ensure that the string is containing either `'0'` and `'1'` characters and we know that the distance between these two is exactly 1 as the digits are consecutive in the character set.

The following expression:

`b[i] - '0'` is going to either be:

- `'1' - '0'` which will return 1
- `'0' - '0'` which will return 0.

Adding that result to the accumulated value `dec` results in appending either a 1 or a 0 to the `dec` accumulator.

---

You could rewrite this expression as `dec = (dec << 1) | (b[i] - '0')`, the compiler likely generates the same code for both expressions.

---

This has some potential issues as the string may be longer than the number of bits of type `unsigned int`, causing the computation to be performed modulo `UINT_MAX+1`, producing the least significant 32 bits of the number on 32-bit systems.

---

The function `binary_to_uint` converts a string of binary digits to the number it represents in binary. You could also use `strtoul(b, NULL, 2)` for this task, but `strtoul` would also accept initial whitespace, a sign and trailing characters and return a different value for very large numbers.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Mind adding an edit to the answer to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

`b[i]` contains either the character `'0'` or the character `'1'` otherwise the function returns `0`.

```
if (b[i] < '0' || b[i] > '1')
    return (0);
```

So subtracting form the character `'0'` or `'1'` the character `'0'` you will get the integer number either `0` or `1`.

```
dec = (2 * dec) + (b[i] - '0');
```

As the string represents a binary representation of a number then `dec` is multiplied by `2` instead of `10`.

Comment: This works because a character literal (`'0'`) is an integer value equal to that character's encoded value, and because the characters for `'0'` through `'9'` are guaranteed to be encoded as consecutive values, so `'9' - '0'` always yields `9`. -- If you see the same done with alphabetic characters, that is an error because those are NOT guaranteed to be consecutively encoded. -- Note that the functionality of this function is covered by the standard function `strtoul( b, NULL, 2 )`.

Comment: Detail: `strtoul( b, NULL, 2 )` allows leading white-space, optional sign and different behavior on overflow.  Other than that, about the same as OP's code.